# do rviz need urdf file for viewing camera feed?

Tags: rviz, urdf, camera, stereo-camera, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a stereo camera, I know that the feed can be viewed in `rviz` using `image` display type.But other than that i want to know how can we succesfully view camera feed  using `camera` display type

- i was successful in calibrating and publishing the `image_info` topic
- but when try to view the camera using `camera` type i get warning status saying no image was received but i successfully gets the image via the `image` display type [image: here i have attached image]
- so my suspicion is if I am missing something on the Fixed_frame or target_frame or something like that

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224964/do-rviz-need-urdf-file-for-viewing-camera-feed?/) by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2016-01-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `Image` display shows a raw image, without aligning it to any of the other sensor data in rviz, so it doesn't require any of the tf frames to be correct.

The `Camera` display shows the image data overlaid with the other data that is visible in rviz, which means that it requires the tf transformations from your fixed_frame to the frame listed in the image message header to be correct. (If you check the terminal where you ran rviz, you will likely see TF errors informing you about this).

If you don't have any other sensors or tf frames set up, you can set your fixed_frame to be the same as your camera frame, and then you should be able to see an image in the Camera view.

(Setting up TF is a topic unto itself. You can use a URDF and robot_state_publisher to publish the TF tree for your robot, or you can use the TF static transform publisher for simpler robots)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Azharudeen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23697/azharudeen/) on 2016-01-24**:
thanks **ahendix** i got the image once i have published tf and then seting the `header.frame_id` of both `image` and `image_info` to the `world` frame